# The effect of the treatment on a coefficient (coefficient difference between treatment and control)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, treatment-effect, lm

I have an experiment where my dependent variable is `Choice`. `Choice` is either `0` or `1`, so I use a `glm` function ( `family = binomial(link=logit)`).

```
    ECOST Choice treatment
 1: 0.076      0         0
 2: 0.190      1         0
 3: 0.066      0         0
 4: 0.207      1         0
 5: 0.062      0         0
 6: 0.199      1         0
 7: 0.076      1         1
 8: 0.190      1         1
 9: 0.066      1         1
10: 0.207      1         1
11: 0.062      1         1
12: 0.199      1         1
13: 0.076      1         0
14: 0.190      1         0
15: 0.066      1         0
16: 0.207      1         0
17: 0.062      1         0
18: 0.199      1         0
19: 0.076      0         0
20: 0.190      0         0
```

**I want to evaluate how the treatment, `treatment==1`, affects the coefficient of `ECOST`, when determining `Choice`.**

**More specifically, I want to evaluate whether the coefficient on `ECOST` is significantly different between the treatment and control group**

Since the sample is a experiment (not a real world situation) I am more interested in significance of the difference than the magnitudes if that makes sense.

Somehow this confuses me a lot. There are a couple of options. I first ran:

```
glm(Choice~ECOST, data=DT, subset=(treatment==0))
glm(Choice~ECOST, data=DT, subset=(treatment==1))
```

Which is essentially what I want, but it does not inform me whether the difference is significant.

I could also do:

```
glm(Choice~ECOST:treatment, data=DT)
```

or

```
glm(Choice~ECOST*treatment, data=DT)
```

The first one does not feel right, because it appears to me that the coefficient incorporates the treatment effect as well. So should it be the second one?

I also tried the following and posted it on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922316/testing-the-signifiance-of-the-difference-of-coefficients-between-two-subsets):

## DATA

I have data as follows:

```
DT <- structure(list(ECOST = c(0.0757999242, 0.190333143, 0.066333267, 
0.2074664592, 0.0615332718, 0.1985331348, 0.0757999242, 0.190333143, 
0.066333267, 0.2074664592, 0.0615332718, 0.1985331348, 0.0757999242, 
0.190333143, 0.066333267, 0.2074664592, 0.0615332718, 0.1985331348, 
0.0757999242, 0.190333143), Choice = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), treatment = structure(c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", 
"numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to test if there is a significant difference between `ECOST` for the `treatment` and non-`treatment` group.

```
    ECOST Choice treatment
 1: 0.076      0         0
 2: 0.190      1         0
 3: 0.066      0         0
 4: 0.207      1         0
 5: 0.062      0         0
 6: 0.199      1         0
 7: 0.076      1         1
 8: 0.190      1         1
 9: 0.066      1         1
10: 0.207      1         1
11: 0.062      1         1
12: 0.199      1         1
13: 0.076      1         0
14: 0.190      1         0
15: 0.066      1         0
16: 0.207      1         0
17: 0.062      1         0
18: 0.199      1         0
19: 0.076      0         0
20: 0.190      0         0
```

I want to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267941/compare-coefficients-across-different-regressions), but when I apply:

```
mm <- glm(Choice~ECOST*treatment,DT, family = binomial(link=logit))
interax <- c("ECOST:treatment")
printCoefmat(coef(summary(mm))[interax,])
```

I get the error:

```
Error in printCoefmat(coef(summary(mm))[interax, ]) : 
  'x' must be coefficient matrix/data frame
```

I guess the problem is that in my case `x` is a single value. How do I do this properly?

EDIT:

```
summary(mm)

Call:
glm(formula = Choice ~ ECOST * treatment, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = DT)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9313  -0.2511   0.0001   0.5538   1.3606  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)        -1.43       1.31   -1.09     0.27
ECOST              16.44      10.35    1.59     0.11
treatment          21.00    9924.86    0.00     1.00
ECOST:treatment   -16.44   66757.70    0.00     1.00

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 22.493  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 15.205  on 16  degrees of freedom
AIC: 23.21

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

Comment: This is mostly a programming question, so off-topic for CV. There is an kernel of statistical question about what the model should look like. Typically, you would include an intercept, treatment dummy, x, and a tretment-x interaction. If you can report the output of summary(mm), perhaps that will make the statistical problem plain.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thank you for your comment. I added `summary(mm)`. Are you saying that the difference is simply the interaction effect on `ECOST:treatment` in `summary(mm)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logit models (like virtually all GLMs) have coefficients that are not directly uninterpretable, and the marginal effects also depend on the values of the data. This means you cannot just look at the interaction coefficient to gauge the magnitude of the effect on the probability.

In your model the change in probability of choosing 1 depends on $x$: $$\Delta \Pr= \Pr(t=1, x_i) - \Pr(t=0, x_i)  = \lambda(-1.43 +16.44 \cdot x_i + 21-16.44 \cdot x_i) - \lambda(-1.43 +16.44 \cdot x_i) = f(x_i)$$
where $\lambda(.)$ is the inverse logit function. This is the difference in probability when treated minus the probability when not.

This effect curve looks like this:

[image]

So the effect of treatment in an increase of 0.8 on a [0,1] scale when x is near zero, but very quickly drops off to essentially zero by $x=0.5$. I have no idea if that range for $x$ is sensible in your data.

This is not the only way to present this model, but the most intuitive for me than something like multiplicative effects on odd-ratios (which just involve exponentiated coefficients).

You can find out how to calculate this kind of curve with a CI using the `margins` package in R [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#Interactions_in_Logit).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to dig into this tomorrow morning.

Comment: I read through your answer a couple of times now. One thing to note about my question (I shall put this in an edit): Since my data is an experiment, the absolute values of the coefficients are not the main focus (as they have no true meaning anyway). The focus is more on comparison of coefficients and significance. I assume however that in order to test whether the coefficient on `x` or `ECOST` is significantly different for the treatment and control group, I still have to use the `CI` from the `margins` package right?

Comment: You also mention that the effect of the treatment is an increase of 0.8 when x/ECOST is near zero, but that it becomes zero, if the change is larger than 0.5. If I look at my data, x/ECOST is never near 0.5. Can I in that case just ignore that part of the curve (as it does not represent any data in my sample)?

Comment: I don't think your interaction intuition from the linear model carries over to the nonlinear test. You can plot the CI or do tests on the effect at various values of $x$. You can also do a more formal hypothesis test comparing the effect at different levels of $x$. On the range question, you should plot the effect with a CI for the range of $x$ that you have. Going beyond involves extrapolating beyond the data, which is mathematically possible but should not be taken very seriously. I also suspect the effect will become insignificant before you get to 0.5.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is all very helpful (although a bit more than I was hoping to get myself into ;)). One last thing before I really want to stop bothering you. If this is was a normal linear regression, would the answer just be the coefficient on the ECOST:treatment interaction in summary (mm) ? I know it is such a simple question (and I assumed this to be the case), but somehow when I think about it some more I always get confused. In any case, thank you for all your help and your time. I'm really grateful for it!

Comment: If this was OLS, there is no link function. The coefficients will not be the same, but assuming they are just for the sake of the example, the ME of treatment would be $21-16.44 \cdot x$. This is also a function of $x$. But the change in the ME from $x$ is constant in OLS. It's just $-16.44$. In the logit, it varies depending on the value of $x$.